# softwareupdated using 350MB+ of memory, is this a problem? How can I get it to use less?

Tags: memory, software-update, launchd

I'm running Yosemite with the latest updates. `softwareupdated` is using approximately 380MB of memory. That seems quite high to me. Is that normal? Is that indicative of a problem?

Does softwareupdated have to be running constantly or can I safely remove it from launchd?

Can I configure softwareupdated to use less memory?

Comment: the answers would be NO, and YES and NO.

Comment: What consequences would there be from removing softwareupdated from launchd? Would that mean that I would not be checking for updates on a schedule?

Comment: correct, but on next restart it will run again unless you disable it totally in the system preferences App Store. As reference, it runs constantly on my Mac but with zero CPU usage (at the moment) and 15 MB memory usage.